# Generic and simple way to upload images from specific nested core data entity on server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary, key-value-coding

I have "Property" entity with to-many relationship with "PLContact" entity. PLContact entity has again to-many relationship with "PhotoGraph" entity.
Something like this:

```
@interface Property (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)insertObject:(PLContact *)value inContactsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromContactsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertContacts:(NSArray<PLContact *> *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeContactsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInContactsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(PLContact *)value;
- (void)replaceContactsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withContacts:(NSArray<PLContact *> *)values;
- (void)addContactsObject:(PLContact *)value;
- (void)removeContactsObject:(PLContact *)value;
- (void)addContacts:(NSOrderedSet<PLContact *> *)values;
- (void)removeContacts:(NSOrderedSet<PLContact *> *)values;
@end

@interface PLContact (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)insertObject:(PLPhotoGraph *)value inPhotoGraphsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromPhotoGraphsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertPhotoGraphs:(NSArray<PLPhotoGraph *> *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removePhotoGraphsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInPhotoGraphsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(PLPhotoGraph *)value;
- (void)replacePhotoGraphsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withPhotoGraphs:(NSArray<PLPhotoGraph *> *)values;
- (void)addPhotoGraphsObject:(PLPhotoGraph *)value;
- (void)removePhotoGraphsObject:(PLPhotoGraph *)value;
- (void)addPhotoGraphs:(NSOrderedSet<PLPhotoGraph *> *)values;
- (void)removePhotoGraphs:(NSOrderedSet<PLPhotoGraph *> *)values;
@end
```

Issue what i am facing is that every photoGraph contains an image against attribute "photo" and i need to upload images on server one-by-one. I need to check every "PhotoGraph" object, if `(photo != nil)`, then upload else leave it.

How can i do all while having "property" object?

I have tried by doing something like converting property entity model to dictionary values.

```
NSDictionary *jsonString = [property dictionaryValues];
```

Then i am getting keyPaths like:

```
- (void) obtainKeyPaths:(id)val intoArray:(NSMutableArray*)arr withString:(NSString*)s forObject:(id)object {
    if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        for (id aKey in [val allKeys]) {
            NSString* path =
            (!s ? aKey : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", s, aKey]);
            id photoGraph = [object valueForKeyPath:path];
            NSLog(@"%@", photoGraph);
            if ([photoGraph isKindOfClass:[PLPhotoGraph class]]) {
                [arr addObject: path];
            }
            [self obtainKeyPaths: [val objectForKey:aKey]
                       intoArray: arr
                      withString: path forObject:object];
        }
    }
    }
```

After getting keyPath, i am uploading images like:

```
for (NSString *keyPath in arr) {
      id photoGraph = [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
        if ([photoGraph isKindOfClass:[PLPhotoGraph class]]) {
            //Upload image now.
        }
    }
```

What is more simple and more generic way for this?

Comment: So why do you store all of your keypaths into an array and then iterate over the array to upload the images?  Why not just upload as soon as you have found the keypath?

Comment: What is a `PLContact` and how is it different from a `Contact`?

Comment: PLContact is actual entity. Contact is nothing..

Comment: @AO yeah i can upload images, i have written down array code for your understanding only.

Comment: @UmairSuraj Your code snippet includes both `Contact` and `PLContact`, and makes it appear that `Contact` is the entity. It's not clear what `PLContact` in your code.

Comment: @TomHarrington actual entity is 'PLContact'..'Contact' is nothing..I have added relational code for just understanding. May be i have missed out writting 'PL' before Contact somewhere..

Comment: @UmairSuraj If "Contact" is nothing, then what is the `@interface Contact` in your code?

Comment: @TomHarrington i have edited post. i think its ok now for you..

Comment: IMHO, the most "Generic and simple way" would be to fetch all PhotoGraph's with a Core Data fetch request. It looks like you are doing the job instead of Core Data.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan How can i fetch PhotoGraph's for a single property, as property has own photoGraphs objects and property has PLContact's and PLContact's have again photoGraphs...

Comment: @UmairSuraj by class name (optionally, you can add some predicate). Use something like that: + (instancetype)fetchRequestWithEntityName:(NSString *)entityName on NSFetchRequest.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan i think you are in wrong direction. Fetching Photograph's will fetch all photoGraphs that are in coreddata, I just need PhotoGraph's objects for specific (single) entity "Property".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and code, you have a single `Property`, and you want to look at its related `PLContact`s and get the photos for each contact. From your code it appears that your data model includes the following:

- Entity `Property` has a to-many relationship called `contacts` whose target is the `PLContact` entity.
- Entity `PLContact` has a to-many relationship called `photoGraphs` whose target is the `PLPhotoGraph` entity.

You're doing things the hard way by looking at every property to see if its value is the right type. You already have Core Data relationships, though so you can just look up the values using the relationship names.

Using key-value coding you can get at the photos by using `[property valueForKeyPath:@"contacts.photoGraphs"]`. But since both `contacts` and `photoGraphs` are to-many relationships, that leaves you with an array of arrays of photos. To get a single a flat array of `PLPhotoGraph` objects you'd do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *allPhotos = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *photoGraphs in [property valueForKeyPath:@"contacts.photoGraphs"]) {
    [allPhotos addObjectsFromArray:photoGraphs];
}
```

When this completes, `allPhotos` has every `PLPhotoGraph` that can be found from the `property` that you started with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch the `Photograph` objects for a given `Property` object ("theProperty"), you need to use a predicate; the correct predicate depends on whether the inverse relationships (from `Photograph` to `Contact` and from `Contact` to `Property`) are "to-one" or "to-many".

If they are both "to-one", and named `contact` and `property` respectively, the predicate would look something like this:

```
NSPredicate *contactPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contact.property == %@",theProperty];
```

If Photograph-Contact is "to-many", and Contact-Property is "to-one":

```
NSPredicate *contactPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY contacts.property == %@",theProperty];
```

Conversely, if Photograph-Contact is "to-one", and Contact-Property is "to-many":

```
NSPredicate *contactPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY contact.properties == %@",theProperty];
```

But if they are *both* "to-many", then you need to use SUBQUERY:

```
NSPredicate *contactPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(contacts, $c, SUBQUERY($c.properties, $p, $p == %@).@count > 0).@count > 0",theProperty];
```

In your comments on one of the other answers, you note that the `Property` objects *also* have a *direct* relationship to `Photograph`.  Again, the correct predicate will depend on whether the inverse is "to-one" or "to-many":

```
NSPredicate *propertyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property == %@", theProperty];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *propertyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY properties == %@", theProperty];
```

Finally, to combine the `propertyPredicate` with the `contactPredicate`, use:

```
fetch.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[propertyPredicate, contactPredicate]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. If it's just about the transfer to a server with no synchronization whatsoever and you have a 1-n-m relationship, why don't you just iterate through both relations with a double for-each-loop, dispatching NSOperations when you find an image?

Sometimes in Obj-C, explicit code is more helpful than generic code. Readablity and simplicity is more important in the long run than 'clever hacks'.

Comment: I am currently iterating and getting all nested PhotoGraph's objects from "Property" and then uploaded all by using NSOperations. Need to say any generic way for getting all nested PhotoGraphs of Property? Something like any predicate that can resolve my issue. Or any Fetch Request way?

Comment: Sure, you can manually construct a fetch request. But ultimately, it will end up being in similar time and memory bounds. What for do you want to sacrifice code readability?

Comment: Also, with the information Core Data has from your model, the getters are probably more efficient than a naive approach to a fetch request.